# Get a dynamic variable with hex code to Tailwindcss with next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

My Task is that I will get a hex code from database and depending on the hex code, colors should change.

variables.js

```js
const primaryColor = "#000000";
const secondaryColor = "#ff0000";
const notCheckedColor = "#9CA3AF";

export { primaryColor, secondaryColor, notCheckedColor };
```

This is an example of code

```
<section className={`bg-white py-12 mt-12  text-${secondaryColor}  sm:py-16 lg:py-20`}>
```

Problem is the color didn't show.

Inspect output

[image]

Thanks as well

I tried to add it statically and it works but when I use `bg-${secondaryColor}` code, it doesn't work.

I expect that hex code return the color to the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Use complete class definitions, like:

  ```js
  const primaryColor = "#000000";
  const secondaryColor = "text-[#ff0000]";
  const notCheckedColor = "#9CA3AF";

  export { primaryColor, secondaryColor, notCheckedColor };
  ```

  ```
  <section className={`… ${secondaryColor} …`}>
  ```
- Use the `style` attribute:

  ```
  <section className="…" style={{ color: secondaryColor }}>
  ```